# Changing cell font colour of a SWT Table

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am using following line on my Eclipse RCP project:

```
item.setForeground(3, dis.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
```

Is there any reason that I don't get the color changed?  I just one particular cell to have red foreground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Eclise-rcp try this one

```
Display display =PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay();
Color red = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
YourTable.getItem(i).setForeground(red);
```

Note: `i` is the index of the table item which you want to change the color.

if you want to change the color of particular cell of particular item the code is

```
YourTable.getItem(i).setForeground(2, red); // 2 means that you column on index 2 will be colored
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to redraw on `Table` after you update foreground/background on `TableItem`. I suggest you to use TableViewer instead Table.